# Ios magnetometer wrong values

Tags: ios, swift, magnetometer, cmmotionmanager

I am writing code to detect magnet. I am doing this through this code:

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()

if manager.isMagnetometerAvailable {
manager.startMagnetometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (data, error) in    
        let bField = sqrt((pow(data?.magneticField.x ?? 0, 2) + pow(data?.magneticField.y ?? 0, 2) + pow(data?.magneticField.z ?? 0, 2)))
        print(bField)    
    }
}
```

problem is that it is printing value above 250 when there is no magnet. This value should be around 50uT if there is no magnet around. Is it raw data? If it is raw data how can I get original data?

Comment: are you trying to say that `data?.magneticField` is not accurate?

Comment: yes, its values are not accurate

Comment: What are the `x`, `y`, `z` values that you're getting? Also did you check it's [calibration](http://w3cgeek.com/is-apples-iphone-magnetometer-calibration-working-properly.html)

Comment: x = 37.316314697265625 :: y = 198.1747283935547 :: z = 186.2473602294922 and I am not check calibration. How can I check for calibration?

Comment: Hm... atleast you're getting values :P Anyways, check: [Is Apple’s iPhone magnetometer calibration working properly?](http://w3cgeek.com/is-apples-iphone-magnetometer-calibration-working-properly.html)